# How do I make my whitenoise static files show up?

Tags: django, whitenoise

Many solutions to this already on SO, but each one is different, and none work for me.
I uploaded my Django/Whitenoise website to Heroku, and the static files stopped working, as usual.
Collectstatic worked and saved them to /staticfiles, but the logo and few images I need won't show up on the website. Does anyone have a cure for this strain of the "Universal but poorly documented Django staticfiles error"?

Filemap:

sfl_website

--website(app)

----website/static(contains my static files)

--staticfiles(where collectstatic sends them)

settings.py

```
STATIC_URL = '/staticfiles/'
STATIC_ROOT = '/Users/Lewis/Documents/sfl_website/staticfiles'
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage'
```

template code

```
{% load static %}
src="{% static "website/images/logo" %}"
```

The logs say: "Not found: static/website/images/logo". Why is it looking there? Where does my code tell it to look?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If logo is an image file, I think you forgot the extension in your template.